# HighCharts Do not display

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

here is my code when i put a string on the name attribute it displays the chart

```
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
            @foreach($usage as $u)
                **['name',   {{$u->cnt}}]**,
            @endforeach


            ]
        }]
```

but when the code goes like this

```
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
            @foreach($usage as $u)
                **['{{$u->dataname}}',   {{$u->cnt}}],**
            @endforeach


            ]
        }]
```

nothing is being displayed.

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console (developer tools in browser) ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan i just put the trim function. I think it has a trailing whitepaces.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks for feedback; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already solved this i just put the trim function.

```
@foreach($usage as $u)    
    ['{{trim($u->dataname)}}',   {{$u->cnt}}],
@endforeach
```